# disable a particular button in a datatable, jsf

Tags: jsf, button, datatable

I have a data table with with two columns- Title and Action
Title is populated from a list in a managed bean and for each title in the list the datatable has a button called Confirm under Action column.
When the user clicks on the Confirm button, a dialog is displayed with additional information and another button called Submit.

If the user hits the Submit button inside that dialog a variable confirmDate is set in the backing bean, of the confirmDate is not null, I need to disable the particular Confirm button under the Action column in the main data table. Right now if I disable it, all the Confirm button is getting disabled. How do I disable only the selected confirm button. Really appreciate your help on this.

main data table

```
<h:panelGrid id="notificationList" width="100%">
<h:panelGroup >                          
  <p:dataTable var="dt" value="#  
  {myBean.listAll}" id="titles" rowKey="#{dt.id}">                                 

    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value = "Title List"/>                                             
    </f:facet>

     <p:column headerText ="Title">
         <h:outputText value="#{dt.title}"/>
     </p:column>

     <p:column headerText="Action">

        <p:commandButton id="nID"                                                      
         value="Confirm"      
         oncomplete="myDialog.show();" 
         process="@this"
         disabled= "#{not empty dt.confirmDate}
         update="@form">

         <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{dt}" target="#
           {myBean.selectedTitle}"/>                                       
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
 </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: I believe you have something wrong in your backing bean or in the way you apply the confirmDate. can you post those code fragments?

Comment: In the managed bean, I was doing something like   public void updateNotificationConfirmDate(){
        selectedNotification1.setConfirmDate((new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())).toString());
        if(selectedNotification1.getConfirmDate() == null)
            setUserChecked(false);
        else
            setUserChecked(true);
         
    }   in the button on pop up dialog the above method is getting called  <p:commandButton value="Submit" disabled = "#{not myBean.userChecked}" action="#myBean.updateNotificationConfirmDate}" oncomplete="notificationDialog.hide()" </p:commandButton>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say with your code, maybe all your `dt` objects which you retrieve via listAll are identical objects. How do you set up the list?

Anyhow this should work (simplified):

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg">
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{myBean.updateNotificationConfirmDate}" oncomplete="dlg.hide()"
        update="notificationList" />
</p:dialog>
<p:dataTable id="notificationList" var="dt" value="#{myBean.tableData}">
    <p:column>
        <p:commandButton value="Confirm" process="@this" disabled="#{!empty dt.confirmDate}" update="@form"
            oncomplete="dlg.show();">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{dt}" target="#{myBean.selectedTitle}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

And the backing bean (whatever your DT is :)):

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {
    private List<DT> tableData = new ArrayList<DT>();
    private DT selectedTitle;

    public MyBean() {
        tableData.add(new DT(1L, "title1", null));
        tableData.add(new DT(2L, "title2", null));
        tableData.add(new DT(3L, "title3", null));
        tableData.add(new DT(4L, "title4", null));

    }

    public DT getSelectedTitle() {
        return selectedTitle;
    }

    public void setSelectedTitle(DT selectedTitle) {
        this.selectedTitle = selectedTitle;
    }

    public List<DT> getTableData() {
        return tableData;
    }

    public void updateNotificationConfirmDate() {
        selectedTitle.setConfirmDate(Calendar.getInstance());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the pointers. I think I hadn't updated the notificationList from the button inside dialog box. After struggling for quite sometime, I decided to render the button only if user has not confirmed the date later on.  <p:commandButton id="nID" rendered="#{dt.confirmDate == null}"             
         value="Confirm"      
         oncomplete="myDialog.show();" 
         process="@this"        
         update="@form">
         <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{dt}" target="#      {myBean.selectedTitle}"/>                                       
        </p:commandButton>